Does order matter in a Nagios configuration?
I want to use the "cfg_dir" directive in my main nagios.cfg to provide a configuration directory containing various local configuration files. Some of the files in my configuration directory refer to things (templates + commands) defined in other files in the same directory.
I believe this is the source code where a configuration directory is read:
https://github.com/NagiosEnterprises/nagioscore/blob/nagios-4.5.3/xdata/xodtemplate.c#L591
This code does not sort the files by name or anything else.
My configuration appears to be working. But I want to know whether this is guaranteed. So, does order matter for directives in the Nagios configuration? Either way, is this documented somewhere?
(Of course, I could provide multiple cfg_file/cfg_dir directives to guarantee ordering. My question is whether I have to.)
